# Dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu (UEFI mode) on a blank HDD.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

My computer came with a FreeDOS. It has a 1 TB HDD and 8 GB RAM. Also, it is a 64 bit processor. Sadly the computer / laptop does not have a CD / DVD ROM drive. Fortunately, it has 4 USB ports. The BIOS support UEFI boot mode.

## What I wish to do:

I want to have a system that can dual boot Windows and Ubuntu 15.10.

## What are the catches here?

I can make a Ubuntu bootable USB key easily, using the `Startup disk creator`. So I did that. I do not know how to make a Windows 10 bootable USB key, for which I possess that ISO image file.

## What attempts did I make?

I took the following steps:

1. Installed `gparted` on an existing Ubuntu system, and formatted an 8 GB pen drive (USB key), in the `ntfs` format.
2. Installed `unetbootin` and attempted to write the Windows 10 iso file to the pen drive.
3. The pen drive fails to boot.

## What do I need to know now:

I need to know the following:

1. How to create a Windows bootable USB key from the available ISO file?
2. How to install Windows in UEFI mode?
3. After Windows is installed which partition mode is to be used for Ubuntu?
4. Will 15.10 install alongside Windows, in UEFI mode and how?

Answer (score 0):

How to create a Windows boot medium is a topic best addressed on a Windows forum, not here. That said, I'd use FAT, not NTFS, and I'd try using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) for the job, or copy files manually from the *UDF* side of the `.iso` image file. (Most Linux tools will mount the ISO-9660 side, which in the case of a Windows disc, contains a text file with a message to the effect that it should be mounted with UDF.)

If your goal is an EFI-mode boot of both OSes, you should disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy boot support" or a similar phrase) in your firmware. The CSM provides BIOS-mode boot compatibility, and as your computer came with FreeDOS (which, AFAIK, boots only in BIOS mode), it's probably active. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on this subject. Note, however, that if you intend to keep FreeDOS in a triple-boot, your best bet is probably to do a BIOS-mode install of all three OSes; I'm assuming you want to ditch FreeDOS entirely, or at most boot it in a virtual machine.

Once Windows is installed, there are hundreds of tutorials for installing Ubuntu. The trouble is that many are poor. One litmus test: If a tutorial tells you to activate the CSM, move on to the next page. (An exception is if this advice applies to certain special cases.)

Here's some more reading for you, including a couple that will help with Ubuntu installation:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than the preceding one.
- **[The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)** -- This page is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.

Answer (score 0):

**How to create a Windows bootable USB key from the available ISO file?**

My preferred option is [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) as it always work. But as its Windows only, I'd recommend following this guide:

[Make A Bootable Windows 10 USB Install Stick On Linux With WinUSB Fork](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html)

**How to install Windows in UEFI mode?**

Make sure your Ubuntu is installed in EFI mode. And your Windows image should support UEFI as well. Then write that image to an usb disk. [Boot the usb device in uefi mode](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/fix-partition-table-issues-win-linux/) and continue with the installation.

Once you install WIndows, your existing Ubuntu installation will most likely to be disappear. But it is not required that you re-install Ubuntu. Just reinstall the grub bootloader.

These should help:

- [Install Windows after Ubuntu](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/)